# Json Parse output isn't the same from the feedback

Tags: flutter, dart

so Im calling the API and getting some return like this :

```
"RC": "00",
    "CMD": "Data",
    "VALUE": {
        "dt_ve": "00",
        "dt_stats": "Success",
        "dt_command": "DATA",
        "dt_invo": "INV",
        "dt_date": "2021-07-07",
        },
```

I made a class filled with the data i want to take

```
class DataTake {

  final String dt_ve;
  final String dt_stats;
  final String dt_command;
  final String dt_date;

  DataTake(this. dt_ve,this. dt_stats ,this. dt_command, this.dt_date);
}
```

made A future Functions

```
Future< DataTake > _getData() async {
    var data = await DataAPI();
    var jsonData = json.decode(data);
    var jsonParse = jsonData["VALUE"];
    final DataTake datatake = DataTake(
        jsonParse['dt_ve'],
        jsonParse['dt_stats'],
        jsonParse['dt_command'],
        jsonParse['dt_date'],
    );
    return datatake;
  }
```

and when I call them using the Future Builder it does not show what they were supposed to show,

when I call

```
Text(
      snapshot.data.dt_date,
      style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 16),
  ),
```

this supposed to show the date

```
"2021-07-07"
```

but rather then showing date it shows

```
"DATA",
```

it means it call "dt_command"

Comment: What is the content if you print the `jsonData` variable?

Comment: its a Map @julemand101

Comment: Yes, I know it is a `Map`. What I want to know is the content of the `Map` structure. E.g. does it contain the expected value of the `dt_date` field so we can pinpoint where your problem is.

Comment: Yes it does @julemand101

Comment: Ok, can you using a debugger verify that the `DataTake` object pointed at by the `datatake` variable has the correct value of `dt_date`? I am trying to find out where in your code the error happens.

Comment: The reason for my questions is that your problem is properly not in the code you have posted here. If I recreate your example in DartPad you can see it works as expected: https://dartpad.dev/63350f391e743da289a3cd4b8bec2a92?null_safety=true